# ASP .NET MVC 5 free use

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, licensing

short question -
may I use ASP .NET MVC 5 web app developed in Visual Studio 2015 Community edition for free and for commercial use (I have no company, just as alone developer) as well as for university purpose?

Another question - is ASP .NET MVC 5 open source? I can´t find good answer to it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may I use ASP .NET MVC 5 web app developed in Visual Studio 2015 Community edition for free and for commercial use (I have no company, just as alone developer) as well as for university purpose?

> Yes you may

Another question - is ASP .NET MVC 5 open source? I can´t find good answer to it.

> You can find the repo below:

[Github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/)

Comment: Thank you very much! @Stoward94